# Illiterate but for Speaking

Tags: adjectives

Is there a word like illiterate but for speaking? A word that just means something along the lines of "unable to speak properly".

Comment: Are you asking about people with speech problems or people with limited vocabulary or something else?

Comment: Or people with good vocabulary, but having trouble expressing oneself? Or not confident with no other problem?

Comment: "Illiterate but for speaking" doesn't mean anything. That's like saying "blind except for the toes". Literacy is about **writing**, not speaking. Many people who speak English can't read it, and many who can read it can't speak it. So I guess there is no word with that meaning.

Answer (score 5):

The adjective "*inarticulate*" describes to a certain extent the problems of someone who can't manage to  combine ideas and words properly.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inarticulate?q=inarticulate))
> **inarticulate** (of speech) not using clear words; not expressed clearly

> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inarticulate#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20inarticulate%20%28Entry%201%20of%202%29%201,incapable%20of%20being%20expressed%20by%20speech%20inarticulate%20fear))
> **inarticulate**  incapable of giving coherent, clear, or effective expression to one's ideas or feelings

Answer (score 1):

An addition near miss is *nonverbal*.

> : lacking or appearing to lack the ability to engage in speech
> She finds she can communicate with nonverbal children using drum beats, for example.
> — Robert S. Greenberger
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonverbal

But it depends on what you mean by opposite of *illiterate*. It has several different senses. I take it to refer somebody who can speak the language but can't read or write. *Nonverbal* carries no such connotation of being able to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***[nonfluency](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonfluency)*** comes close to what you are looking for.

> - lack of fluency

(M-W)